# Mysterious motel and other wierd things/items

Tags: identify-this-movie

Unfortunatly I can't remember much about this movie I'm looking for.

- The protagonist (I think male) visits a motel multiple times throughout the movie. There is a specific room in which some paranormal things happen.
- One item in the movie is some sort of ID (I remember a scene in a hospital, maybe an employees ID card)
- The ID card is in a plastic case and can be carried safely, but if you touch the actual card one gets teleported away
- I think the place you get teleported to was some kind of highway in the middle of nowhere
- I have an image in my head that the protagonist has a daughter, but I could be mixing this up with some other movie.
- The movie must be at least 10 years old

Again, I'm sorry for not providing any more details, this is all I can remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like the miniseries [The Lost Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room) from 2006 that starred Peter Krause, Elle Fanning, Julianna Margulies and Kevin Pollak.

> The series revolves around the titular [motel] room and some of the everyday items from that room which possess unusual powers. The show's protagonist, Joe Miller, is searching for these objects to rescue his daughter, Anna, who has disappeared inside the Room.

Once you touch the bus ticket from that motel room, [you're transported to the middle of Route 66](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUSa8DOke-c).
Here's the trailer:

Comment: If you like that, I can advise you to also check [Parallels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3479316/) a movie from the creator of the show.